# Objects classes and Member Function

Tags: c++, pointers

Executed with Online GDB Compiler.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test {
public:
  int x = 5;
  double z = 5.89999;
  float y = 6.7;

  void print(){
    int m;
    cout << "Print Method" << endl;
  }
};

int main(){
  test t;

  cout << *(int*)((char*)&t + offsetof(test, x)) << endl;
  cout << *(float*)((char*)&t + offsetof(test, y)) << endl;
  cout << *(double*)((char*)&t + offsetof(test, z)) << endl;

  //Accessing the pointer to the member function

  void (test::*mf)() = &test::print;

  //Can we do the above statement using pointer arithmetic

  //Making a call to it

  (t.*mf)();

  //Can we do the above statement using pointer arithmetic?
}
```

Output:

```
5
6.7
5.89999
Print Method
```

I might have a lot of mistakes in my understanding, so kindly excuse me.

A function name points to the starting address of the code segment of its own function.

1. I created a pointer to the member function `void (test::*mf)()` and it is assigned with the pointer of the member function `print`. How can I access the member function's address using the class name? Where does the class name reside in memory, and how is it associated to the member function with respect to the address and memory space?
2. Memory space gets allocated for the member fields once the object is created, and objects don't have the pointer to the code segment of the member functions. So, a pointer to a member function is not part of the object, but can be invoked by the object. How does the object get a hold of that member function's pointer, and where is it hiding?
3. `void (test::*mf)() = &test::print;`

   Can I do the above statement using pointer arithmetic?

   `(t.*mf)();`

   Can I do the above statement using pointer arithmetic?

Comment: DO NOT SPAM TAGS! How this question is related to the C language?

Comment: If you really want to tinker with undefined behavior, the baseclass of your class has to have virtual methods eg `virtual void print() = 0`. Without it, C++ tries really hard to make the class disappear from existence at compile time, and inlines the methods as much as possible unless you explicitly try taking addresses of them.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I access the member function's address using the class name?

You don't.

> Where does the class name reside in memory, and how is it associated to the member function with respect to the address and memory space?

The class name is not stored anywhere (well, except maybe in RTTI memory, but we'll ignore that since it is not relevant to this discussion).

The compiler knows that the member function is associated with the class, so it can perform access checks and such.  And the compiler knows what kind of object the member function is being called on, so it can pass the object in the function's hidden `this` parameter.  But the actual code segment of the function is stored elsewhere in memory, and the compiler doesn't knows where that actually is.  All it can do is make reference to it, and then the linker will fill in that reference with the appropriate memory access when creating the executable file.

> Memory space gets allocated for the member fields once the object is created, and objects don't have the pointer to the code segment of the member functions. So, a pointer to a member function is not part of the object, but can be invoked by the object. How does the object get a hold of that member function's pointer

It doesn't.  The object doesn't invoke anything.  The compiler does, it generates a normal function call like any other, but it passes the address of the associated object as the function's hidden `this` parameter.

> and where is it hiding?

It is not hiding anywhere.

> Can I do the above statement using pointer arithmetic?

No, to both, because the code segment of a member function is not part of the object's allocated memory, like data members are, so you can't reach a member function by calculating an address relative to the object itself.

Comment: The object doesnt invoke anything the compiler does.., So first tried creating an object to a class then deleted that object then using the pointer  called the member function it worked. Then just created a pointer to a class and called the member function again it worked.
```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test{
    public:
    void print(){
        cout<<"Print Method";
    }
};

int main(){
    test *t;
    t->print();
}```

Comment: Can you please give us some insight about this.
Do have some knowledge about the symbol table name, type, scope, offset...etc
can you please give the representation of the class in the symtab.

Comment: @PraveenKumarKarthikeyan calling a method on an invalid object is *undefined behavior*, so anything can happen, including it appearing to work. Try making the method access data members of the object and you will get a much different result. But all of the other things you asked for are way out of scope of the original question, consult books that cover those topics.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use pointers with

```
test t; test * p_t = &t; p_t ->print();
```

I think this is a better choice when you have just created a great pointer that has one object to use concurrently.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).